# Finding the slow stored procedures from a Trace file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

Client from their production environment send me a trace file.
I want to know which stored procedures are taking longest.

The things they record in the trace file include:  `RPC:Starting , RPC:Completed`

I noticed in in the trace columns we have both `StartTime/EndTime`  and also `Duration`.

Which one should I use for my purpose?

And to know how long a SP took, so Should I find the difference between `StartTime` of `RPC:Starting` and `EndTime` of `RPC:Completed`?

Comment: The duration should give you what you require, but if you sort by that with the largest first, you should see the start and end dates/times are the longest too.

Comment: Duration will show you the slowest but the ones with high Reads are the ones you can best improve.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, you can run the Stored Procedure using the Display Estimated Execution Plain (CTRL + L) tool contained in SQL Management Studio.

[image]

It will demonstrate the cost of time and execution of each.

I hope I have helped.

Comment: Thanks but the trace is from a production DB of a customer that I don't have access to their database.  Would it still run ?